# Geeting dropdown options, with suggestions on top

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a dropdown component, and this is what I have so far:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-shannon-xzmnr?file=/src/Component.js)

I'm wondering if there is a better way to get these suggestions on top? It kind of works right now, where the name is one word, but if the test data is full of objects, such as,

```
const testData = [
  { name: 'abc 123' },
  { name: 'def 123' },
  . . .
]
```

Then it correctly recognises the matches, but it doesn't order them correctly, because it doesn't sort the suggestions array after the `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just chain an [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on to your reduce function since it returns an array. The reason for [`localCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) in the sort function is because we are sorting strings.

```
const dropDownOpionsRest = testData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const match = regex.test(item.name);
  console.log("match", item, match);
  if (match) {
    dropDownSuggestions.push(item);
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }

  return acc;
}, []).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

dropDownSuggestions.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

console.log([...dropDownSuggestions, ...dropDownOpionsRest]);
```